# Some directories not included on File.listfiles() call

Tags: android, filesystems

In an app I'm working on I have a file manager that uses `File.listFiles()` to retrieve all the files in a directory. This works perfectly fine on a `Samsung Galaxy S3` but on a `Nexus 7 tablet` with `KitKat 4.4.2` some of the directories are missing. The app has permissions to read and write to external storage.

The directories missing are particularly the ones I created recently. I checked the permissions on those and they are the same as the directories that get listed (771). Other file managing apps are able to list them all. Would this be a problem with the system not reindexing the directories?

Is there an alternative to `File.listFiles()` that would work better?
Obviously the other file managing apps are using a different method since they work fine.

I've tried some suggestions I found online about forcing a media re-scan but all the apps that I tried crash (seems to be an Android 4.4 related issue).

EDIT: I seem to have found the reason, which still puzzles me. There was a call to a function getFileExtension() that was returning NULL and caused some directories to no get listed. The call was done only if the item was not a directory but somehow it affected the execution flow:

```
if (ff.isDirectory()) {
   dir.add(new Option(ff.getName(), "Folder", ff.getAbsolutePath()));
} else {
   if (getFileExtension(ff.getName()).matches("WAV|AIFF|AIF|AMB|MP3|OGG|FLAC")) {
       fls.add(new Option(ff.getName(), String.valueOf(ff.length()), ff.getAbsolutePath()));
   }
}
```

The funny thing is that the same code ran OK on the Galaxy S3 (with Android 4.3).

Comment: Media re-scan will not help. media scan means whether files are visible for other apps like if you save image file and if it's scanned it will be visible in gallery.